# SQL Server 2017 identity value jumped backward

Tags: sql-server

I've noticed before that sometimes when a network error occurs, the identity value in SQL Server tables jumps 1000 units forward as your last row has id=153 and the next row takes the value of id=1153.

But today I had a strange situation, where the last row had id=12 and the current identity value was reset to 4 so that attempts to insert new rows caused server error. I searched but didn't find anything, and resorted to resetting identity value manually.

Does anyone know the reason and how to prevent it?

My SQL Server version is 2017 (v14.0).

I'm also using Ef Core 3.1 ORM, but I don't think it has anything to do with it.

Comment: The value of the seed won't go backwards unless someone changed the value of said seed; the functionality that the value always increase is guaranteed. This means that *someone* changed the seed's value.

Comment: As for skipping values, this is a known, expected, and desired behaviour. `IDENTITY` has never been designed to be sequential, and should never be expected to be.

Comment: We need to focuse on network errors and type of them. is your SQL Server local or seprated from the codes? Any retry function on fail query?

Comment: @MiladAbooali Jumping forward isn't really a problem. My real problem was jumping backward, and according to answers, it was a human error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the gap of 1000 value in the Identity is `DENTITY_CACHE`. SQL Server generates and caches the next 1000 identity values for a table. SQL Server does this for the improve the performance of the INSERT statements which runs on the table. However, due to the unexpected crash scenario or server restart, it also loses the pre-generated identity value and that behavior is responsible for the 1000 value jump in the identity.

As @Larnu said `IDENTITY` has never been designed to be sequential, and should never be expected to be.
I guess It could be caused by deletion and rollback, when you inserted data are rejected by constraints or triggers.

You can reset the identity column value:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TableName', RESEED, 1)
```

Comment: *"As @Larnu said SQL Server guarantees that the next number generated will be unique"* I never said it would be unique. Uniqueness is **not** guaranteed by an `IDENTITY`; that's what a `UNIQUE INDEX`/`UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` is for.

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of SQL Server 2017, the SQL Server team introduced a new database configuration options named "IDENTITY_CACHE" that can be turned on and off. This new database configuration options allows you to disable the identify cache by database. By disabling the identity cache, you can avoid the large gap in identity column values when SQL Server should crash or be shut down unexpectedly.